# Implement Server-Side Rendering for Multi-Page React App with C# Backend

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on a multi-page React application and I'm trying to implement server-side rendering (SSR) using C# and ASP.NET Core on the backend. I'm encountering challenges in getting the React components to render on the server and properly hydrate on the client side. Here's what I've done so far:

1. I've set up Webpack to enable server-side rendering using React and Liquid templates. I have separate entry points for different pages.
2. I'm using `renderToString` to render the React components on the server. However, the rendering isn't working as expected.

Here's a simplified structure of my files:

- `webpack.config.js`: I've set up Webpack with configurations to enable server-side rendering. The application architecture involves React, Express for the server, and Liquid templates for rendering. I've established distinct entry points for various pages, which I believe facilitates a modular approach to SSR.

```
    const path = require("path");
    var config = {
        mode: "development",
        target: "web",
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.liquid']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: 'babel-loader'
                }
            ]
        }
    };
    
    var configSet = [];
    function createConfigObj(key, entryFilePath, OutputJSName) {
        obj = Object.assign({}, config, {
            name: key,
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, entryFilePath),
            output: {
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/static/bundle"),
                filename: OutputJSName
            },
            optimization: {
                splitChunks: {
                    cacheGroups: {
                        vendor: {
                            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                            name: 'vendor', // Use 'vendor' as the vendor chunk name
                            chunks: 'initial', // Extract common dependencies from entry points
                            filename: 'vendor.js', // Set a different filename for the vendor chunk
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    
        configSet.push(obj); // Add the configuration to the configSet array
    }
    createConfigObj("configHelp", "src/help", "help.js");
    createConfigObj("configHome", "src/index", "index.js");
    createConfigObj("configHttp", "src/http", "http.js");
    module.exports = configSet;
```

- `webpack.server.js`: I've configured Webpack to enable server-side rendering, utilizing React, Express, and Liquid templates. Different entry points are set up for various pages, allowing for a modular SSR approach

```
    const path = require('path');
    const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
    
    module.exports = {
        mode: "development",
        target: 'node',
        entry: './server.js',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.liquid']
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/static/bundle'),
            filename: 'server.js',
        },
        externals: [nodeExternals()],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.liquid$/,
                    use: 'liquid-loader',
                },
            ],
        },
    };
```

- `server.js`:  The server.js script is where the server-side rendering process begins. I'm using renderToString to render React components on the server. However, the rendering process doesn't seem to produce the expected outcome

```
    const React = require('react');
    const express = require('express');
    const fs = require('fs'); // Import the fs module
    const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
    const { StaticRouter } = require('react-router-dom');
    const App = require('./src/app');
    
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static('./assets/static/bundle')); // Serve your bundled React app
    
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      const context = {};
      const appHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
          <App />
        </StaticRouter>
      );
    
      if (context.url) {
        res.redirect(context.url);
        return;
      }
    
      // Read the content of index.liquid using fs.readFileSync
      const templateContent = fs.readFileSync('./templates/index.liquid', 'utf-8');
    
      // Replace the placeholder with the appHtml
      const html = templateContent.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${appHtml}</div>`);
      res.send(html);
    });
    
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
    });
```

- `index.liquid`: The index.liquid template is tailored for the home page. Liquid tags are used to generate dynamic content and asset URLs. This template encapsulates the rendered React components and it contains div id="root" for index.js.

  - `index.js`: The index.js file serves as the React entry point for the home page. This is where the React application is initialized and subsequently rendered on the client side.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { hydrateRoot } from "react-dom/client";
    import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
    import App from "./app";
    
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    
    if (rootElement && rootElement.innerHTML.trim().length === 0) {
      // Perform server-side rendering
      const { renderToString } = require("react-dom/server");
      const { StaticRouter } = require("react-router-dom");
    
      // Server-side rendering
      const context = {};
      const appHtml = renderToString(
        <StaticRouter location={window.location.pathname} context={context}>
          <App />
        </StaticRouter>
      );
      hydrateRoot(rootElement, <BrowserRouter>{appHtml}</BrowserRouter>);
    } else {
      hydrateRoot(rootElement, <App />);
    }
```

- `App.js`: The App.js file is the central React component representing the home page. It displays core content and navigation links.

In my `Startup.cs` file, I've set up middleware, static files, authentication, and error handling. I'm also using Swagger for API documentation.

Here's a summarized version of my `Startup.cs`:

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Middleware and configuration setup
    
        // Static files setup
    
        // Authentication setup
    
        // Error handling setup
    
        // Swagger setup
    }
```

I have done the above things with help from internet and am unable to know what needs to be done on the C# side. Can someone guide me through the proper approach to implementing server-side rendering for a multi-page React application using C# and ASP.NET Core? Are there any best practices or common issues I should be aware of?

I greatly appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: 1) Microsoft discontinued support for the NodeServices 2) The react app must be hosted through the asp.net core app. There are several forks of the [SpaServices.Prerendering](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices) project. But I don't have experience with react